# pre-commit hooks go: errors parsing go.mod: usage: require module/path v1.2.3

Tags: git, go, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm new to Go and trying to follow [this tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/database-access) but in a Github repo. I'm on Mac OS 12.6 and my Go version is 1.19.1. My repo structure is:

```
usership
│   go.mod
│   go.sum
│   main.go
│   .pre-commit-config.yaml
│   .pre-commit-hooks.yaml
└─── data-access
│   │   create-tables.sql
└─── vendor
│   │   modules.txt
│   └─── github.com
│   │   └─── go-sql-driver
│   │   │   └─── ...
```

My pre-commit-config.yaml and pre-commit-hooks.yaml files come from [here](https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang).

When I `go run main.go` I get the desired output (MySQL connection).

But when I try to `git commit` with `main.go` staged, I get a bunch of errors in my pre-commit hooks. There appear to be 2 types:

1. `go: errors parsing go.mod: /usership/go.mod:3: usage: require module/path v1.2.3`
2. `gocritic not installed or available in the PATH please check https://github.com/go-critic/go-critic`

My go.mod file looks like:

```
module github.com/dopaminegirl19/usership

go 1.19

require github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.6.0
```

I've also run `go install -v github.com/go-critic/go-critic/cmd/gocritic@latest` and don't get any errors but I'm not 100% sure it works - should I get a confirmation message in my shell? My GOPATH is empty if that helps.

Thanks for any help!

**edit: solved**

For the first problem I no doubt had some issues in my pre-commit-config.yaml file because making it again from scratch, then uninstalling and re-installing pre-commit made the problem go away.

For the second, it was a $GOPATH problem which I solved with:

```
> export $GOPATH="$HOME/go"
> PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

Thanks team!

Comment: you shouldn't need a `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` file -- that's for _providing_ hooks.  please show your full output -- you're likely running into one specific tool that's the actual problem and pre-commit isn't (it just runs tools)

Comment: Never use `go run`, it's basically just a toy. The complaint about line 3 is odd since the `require` looks well formed *and* is on line *five*, not line *three*. Something is very wonky in your setup somewhere...